# How do I use specific module in Qiskit Runtime?

Tags: qiskit, python

I am using qiskit runtime and I need to serialize a class pass it in json format and rebuild the class once the program is uploaded. For this I wanted to use

`import jsonpickle`

which would make it very simple but if I try to import it I get the error:

`ERROR Failed to execute program: No module named 'jsonpickle'`

Is there a way to import this library using qiskit runtime?

Comment: It's really hard to debug a random error with no context.  We don't even know which module wasn't found. Could you show us a snippet of code, and where the error occurred?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the module isn't installed? In your python environment, try:

```
$ pip install jsonpickle
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the modules should be installed, check if the module exists with the following command:

```
pip list | grep jsonpickle
```

or

```
phyton -m jsonpickle
```

if it does not exist, consider importing it:

```
pip install jsonpickle
```

I hope this helped you.